# Possible to iterate COM object events in managed code (C#) for dynamic eventhandler assignment?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, unmanaged, managed

I have a native C++ application that exposes a COM interface with a number of events; plugins subscribe to a subset of these events. I've added support for CLR hosting in the application and written a custom host/appdomainmanager interface that loads a C# "loader" assembly which inherits from AppDomainManager (loosely based on example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416471/CLR-Hosting-Customizing-the-CLR) which is working properly to load managed plugins for my application. The issue I'm working on now is that I'd like to be able to hookup the application events to managed plugin callback functions via the loader dynamically; I want to iterate through every event that the application exposes via the COM interface, find a matching function (name/params) in the plugin, and attach the eventhandler. On the managed (plugin) side, this is possible via the Reflection APIs (iterating through the plugin assembly and checking types/methods), but I'm wondering if it's possible to get a collection of the events exposed via the COM interface from the unmanaged side. I'm using the special tlbimp event/delegate types to hook up the event handlers statically now:

```
appInterface.Function += new _IApplicationEvents_FunctionEventHandler(Function);
```

Is there any way I can get around explicitly hooking up each event handler this way or am I stuck? What I'm wondering is if there's some way to iterate through the special delegate types created via the interop and grab the same kind of name/param info that is available via the Reflection API for managed classes.

Comment: Big Mistake.  Expose an Appliation object with events.  *Always* leave it up to the client code to decide which events it is interested in.  Avoid the God complex, you have no idea what Eve is going to do.  Compare to the Office extension model.

Comment: Food for thought, I'll consider whether this is the best option or not, thanks. The idea is not to force the client code, it's to simplify the procedure for plugin developers. Most of our plugin authors are not real programmers and I was attempting to spare them dealing with interop delegates etc. But maybe the better choice is to provide thorough documentation including the names of each interop-generated delegate and let them sort it out.